# How to run silverstripe online project on localhost?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am new to silverstripe, I have a running silverstripe project on server i want to change some code on that project, so iwant run it on my localhost, how can i install it again in my localhost, because in site _config file contain some other plugin code so i can't re-install in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of creating a local development version of a Silverstripe site would be very similar to that of [deploying a site to a live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344995/silverstripe-cms-installation-and-development/21379075#21379075).

Here is one way to download and set up a Silverstripe website from a live server.

1. Connect to the live server through ftp
2. Download all the files from the server to your local development folder
3. Create a database on your local server
4. Update your local development `mysite/_config.php` file with your development database username, password and database name
5. Dump your live database
6. Import your database dump into your development database
7. Call `dev/build/?flush=all` on your development site
8. Check the website works
9. Have a beer

**Database settings**

The database settings are stored in `mysite/_config.php`. They should look something like this:

```
$databaseConfig = array(
    'type' => 'MySQLDatabase',
    'server' => 'localhost', 
    'username' => 'database_username', 
    'password' => 'database_password', 
    'database' => 'database_name'
);
```

This is where you would change the database username, password and database name to that of your development database settings.